# How to install bootstrap, jquery in ruby on rails 7 using importmaps?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-5

Webpacker is dead, so how to install bootstrap, jquery on ruby on rails 7 using importmaps

Comment: Pls any one help me out, thanks in advance

Comment: *Webpacker is dead*, but webpack is still alive and the best option for rails 7 on my opinion